# What wrong with this Scala loop in reading files

Tags: scala

I am using Scala to read data from 2 CSV files and for each line from the first file, I want to scan all line from the second CSV file to do some calculating.
This is my code

```
object CSVProcess extends App {

  val dataMatlab = io.Source.fromFile("./data/data_matlab1.csv")
  val matchDataMatlab = io.Source.fromFile("./data/match_data_matlab1.csv")

  for ((line, count) <- dataMatlab.getLines.zipWithIndex) {
    for ((line1, count1) <- matchDataMatlab.getLines.zipWithIndex) {
      println(s"count count1  ${count} ${count1}")
    }

  }
  dataMatlab.close
  matchDataMatlab.close
```

However, the output does not like what I expect, the loop stops when the first line of the first CSV file scans all lines of the second one. 
For example, in the CSV 1, There are 3 lines

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
```

In the CSV 2, It has3 lines

```
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
```

But the output is

```
count count1  0 0
count count1  0 1
count count1  0 2
```

The output  should be

```
count count1  0 0
count count1  0 1
count count1  0 2
count count1  1 0
count count1  1 1
count count1  1 2
count count1  2 0
count count1  2 1
count count1  2 2


.
```

Could someone detect the problem of my code

Comment: It is n line for the file 1 and n1 for the file 2, and the loop should be n*n1 times.

Comment: What's your expected output? It's the fact that the above output is what your code aims to do. So tell me your expected output & make sure that your test data files are both ok.

Comment: Hi, I just have edited the question, I add an example for my case

Comment: And I have explained the reason of the behavior and the solution :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much, you are amazing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `io.Source.fromFiles("path").getLines` gives you a `iterator` and `Iterators` are like *socket buffers* meaning that once you read a data out of it, there would be no data left.

[official scala documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html) explains as

> > `An iterator is not a collection, but rather a way to access the elements of a collection one by one. The two basic operations on an iterator it are next and hasNext. A call to it.next() will return the next element of the iterator and advance the state of the iterator. Calling next again on the same iterator will then yield the element one beyond the one returned previously...`

The solution would be to convert the iterators to any of the traversables. Here I have converted to List for persistance.

```
  val dataMatlab = io.Source.fromFile("./data/data_matlab1.csv").getLines().toList
  val matchDataMatlab = io.Source.fromFile("./data/match_data_matlab1.csv").getLines().toList

  for ((line, count) <- dataMatlab.zipWithIndex) {
    for ((line1, count1) <- matchDataMatlab.zipWithIndex) {
      println(s"count count1  ${count} ${count1}")
    }

  }
```

now you should get the expected output

I hope the explanation is clear enough and helpful

Comment: Yeah, You are amazing, sadly, I could not vote for you because my reputation less than 15. I

Comment: thats alright :) you can come back and upvote when you would be capable. Glad that the answer is helpful